# Finding locus of circle passing through extremities of the two rods

Tags: geometry, circles

Two thin rods AB and CD of length 2a and 2b moves along OX and OY where O is the origin. Find the locus of the center of the circle passing through the extremities of the two rods.

---

**My attempt:-**

There are two points (2a,0) and (0,2b) through which the circle passes,
So let the center C be (h,k) and radius r

$(h-2a)^2 + k^2 = r^2$

$h^2 + (k-2b)^2 = r^2$

$(h-2a)^2 + k^2 = h^2 + (k-2b)^2$

$-4ax+4a^2  = -4bk + 4b^2$

$a^2-b^2  = ax-bk$
I don't know what to do next.

The correct answer is $x^2-y^2  = a^2-b^2$

Comment: The extremities form a set of $4$ points, and there is not always a circle passing through $4$ points. Is there some specific way in which the rods move?

Answer (score 1):

My attempt

Length of intercept on y-axis

$$ 2b =2√(g^2-c)$$

Length of intercept on x-axis

$$ 2a =2√(f^2-c)$$
From the above equations you get

$$(g^2 - a^2)=(f^2-b^2)$$
From this we would get

$$g^2 -f^2 = a^2 -b^2$$

where (g,f) is the centre of the circle.  Replace (g,f) by (x,y), and you would get the answer:

$$ x^2 -y^2 = a^2 - b^2 $$

Comment: You should format your posts with MathJax for them to be readable properly. Here are some tips: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference?